# How to check existence of a file in network with c# in .net mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, networking, file-exists

I'm trying to reach a file in network but it gives me the error the path is not found.
What should i do to check existence of a file in network with c# in .net MVC 3

```
File.Exists("\\102.102.112.250\\some_pictures\\" + apicturename + ".jpg")
```

This is the network adress `\\102.102.112.250\some_pictures`

did my research but still couldnt find a proper answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just need to escape the `\` at the beginning of your path:

```
File.Exists("\\\\102.102.112.250\\some_pictures\\" + apicturename + ".jpg")
```

Alternatively you could probably use:

```
File.Exists(@"\\102.102.112.250\some_pictures\" + apicturename + ".jpg")
```

Which is a little easier to read since you are not needing to escape the `\` in a verbatim string.

Answer (score 1):

Create a network share that points to the same place and use the share instead of the ip to check for the file existence.